# Fire a drl rule in Drools guvnor from eclipse programmatically

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor

I am a newbie in Drools guvnor.I have created a rule using Rest API(Webclient) programmatically. but i am  unable to fire this rule from my eclipse.

Can anyone please provide me some code snippet "How to fire a rule programmatically using rest API"

Answer (score 0):

Guvnor is just a container for your rules. Something like a repository. Rules are never executed inside Guvnor (the only exception are test scenarios). What you have to do is to get your rules (or package) using REST API, and create a KnowledgeBase with them. You can get more information here: http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.5.0.Final/drools-expert-docs/html_single/#d0e2354

Hope it helps,